# Show for a set, that it is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $T$ be any index set and $(\Omega_t,\mathcal{A}_t)_{t\in T}$ a family of measurable spaces. Furthermore consider $\mathcal{A}:=\bigotimes_{i\in T}\mathcal{A}_i$ and 
> >     $$
> > \mathfrak{A}:=\left\{A\subset\prod_{i\in T}\Omega_i|~\exists~R\subset T~\text{countable }: A\in\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{i\in R}\mathcal{A}_i\right)\right\},
> > $$
> >     whereat
> >     $$
> > \pi_R^T:=\pi_R\colon\prod_{i\in T}\Omega_i\to\prod_{i\in R}\Omega_i,~~(\omega_i)_{i\in T}\longmapsto(\omega_i)_{i\in R}.
> > $$

Good evening!

As an alternative to [Show identity between product-$\sigma$-algebra and a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640786/show-identity-between-product-sigma-algebra-and-a-set), I would like to show, that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Here's my try of a proof:

The first thing I have to show is that

- $\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t\in\mathfrak{A}$,

i.e. that there exists a countable subset $R\subset T$ so that $\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t\in\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t\right)$.

My idea is to choose $R:=\left\{t\right\}$ for a $t\in T$. Then it is
$$
\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t=\pi_{R}^{-1}(\Omega_t)\in\pi_R^{-1}(\mathcal{A}_t)\implies\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t\in\mathfrak{A}.
$$

The next thing to show is

- $A\in\mathfrak{A}\implies A^C\in\mathfrak{A}$

Let $A\in\mathfrak{A}$. Then there exists a countable $R\subset T$ so that $A=\pi_R^{-1}(B)$ for a $B\in\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t$. Do not know if this is thought too easy, but then it is
$$
A^C=\left\{x\in\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t: x\notin A\right\}\\=\left\{x\in\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t: x\notin \pi_R^{-1}(B)\right\}\\=(\pi_R^{-1}(B))^C=\pi_R^{-1}(B^C)\in\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t\right),
$$
because $B^C\in\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_T$. So $A^C\in\mathfrak{A}$.

Last thing to show is

- $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathfrak{A}^{\mathbb{N}}\implies\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\in\mathfrak{A}$

I am not sure if I am right here, but I try.

Consider $(A_n)\in\mathfrak{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$. That means for any $A_n$ there exists a countable $R_n\subset T$ so that $A_n=\pi_{R_n}^{-1}(B_n)$ for a $B_n\in\bigotimes_{t\in R_n}\mathcal{A}_t$. Then I define
$$
R:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}R_n.
$$
$R$ is countable subset of $T$.

Furthermore, it is for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
\pi_{R_n}^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{t\in R_n}\mathcal{A}_t\right)\subset\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t\right).
$$

That means that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $A_n=\pi_R^{-1}(C_n)$ for a $C_n\in\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t$.

From this it follows
$$
\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\pi_R^{-1}(C_n)=\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n\right)\in\pi_R^{-1}\left(\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t\right),
$$
because of $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n\in\bigotimes_{t\in R}\mathcal{A}_t$.

---

Now I would like to know, if my proof is right.

Can you give me a feedback or help if necessary?

With greetings!

math12

Comment: It seems to me that the definition of product sigma algebra readily implies that $\mathcal{A} = \mathfrak{A}$.

Comment: I think your proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: @hot_queen Don't know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That sounds great! Hehe